# Can't deploy war on Apache Tomcat 6

Tags: eclipse, deployment, tomcat6, war

I'm using 64 bits Debian Squeeze and working on eclipse, I tried to deploy a war file by pasting it into the Tomcat's webapps folder but it didn't deploy the war file, I checked and Tomcat was running. I reinstalled Tomcat but nothing changed.

What's happening? This is the first time I have this kind of trouble deploying war files on Tomcat.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to add the info i get from the Catalina.out file:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:72)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:48)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:70)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:148)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:886)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:1021)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5707)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4449)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
5/10/2011 01:19:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file: error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4320)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4489)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably a big war file and/or you tomcat is not on the same physical drive.
Tomcat detects that you try to deploy something before the copy finishes.

Stop your tomcat, put your war in webapps, restart it, and it should work.

Or

Copy it first into the tomcat root folder and then move it to webapps.

Answer (score 1):

Quick checklist:

- test the integrity of your zip with `unzip -t app.war`,
- check that the user of the tomcat process has permissions to read the war file.